# Changing the display name of field in the template does not reflect the name at item level

Tags: templates, fieldtype

I had created a template in Sitecore 9.0.2 named as XYZ, and had a field in that named as "Test". 
Now the client wants to change the name of the field "Test" to "Test1".

I changed the display name of the field in the template section where the field resides, and instantly could see the changed name of the field in the field section of the template under the templates root.

For some reason i could not see the updated field name in the items that were created using that template in the content tree. Is this the default Sitecore behavior, because the item still show the actual name of the field.

I googled a little and found the solution was to change the "Title" field of the field value that I had earlier renamed and it worked also. But i thought that display name should have also had the same effect.
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Are you sure Tamás? I also thought it was the Title field.. but it might have changed since I learned how to do that :)

Comment: @Gatogordo I think you are right, I just deleted my comment after I saw your answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding is not correct.

It is indeed the `Title` field which is displayed above the Field in the Content Editor. By default, this is set to the Field’s name, but you may change the value if you wish.

If you want to display even more information, you can use the `Help` section (`Long Description` and `Short Description`) as explained in this Q/A: [How to add helpful text to a Sitecore field](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/387/237)

The `display name` is used to show the in the content tree (if enabled for that user) or to use in the generated url of the item (if enabled in your url options). Setting this value on a template field has actually no use (it might even confuse other developers, so I never do that)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Can you point out the difference between display name and the title of the field?

Comment: Updated answer with clarification on the display name

Comment: Exactly, its the Title value for a field which will appear in item and not the display name. Display name in case of fields is a presentable name for the field in content tree. It is the title value which actually appears in the item along with the Help text.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed understanding. My query has been cleared!